# ActionController::UnknownFormat in CoinsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In my CoinsController, I have added a respond_to method in my index controller. I'm not sure if my code is right but here is my index controller below:

```
def index
    paginated = paginate(Coin.recent)
    render_collection(paginated)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do 
        format.html # index.html.erb        
        format.json { render json: render_collection(paginated) }
      end
    end
  end
```

I read the few documents I found online about respond_to do |format| method and when I tried adding it manually the way it is in the documentation, I get an Unknown Format error. What I'm trying to do is have logic that handles both html and json, so that it can act as a json api and a view renderer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys so I found out the solution to my problem:

```
def index
    paginated = paginate(Coin.recent)
    # render_collection(paginated)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render_collection(paginated)
      end
      format.html do
        render :index
      end
    end
  end
```

I had commented out the render_collection(paginated) and then added json and html to it's own block and it worked.